# How to get entire classpath of the modules added to wildfly server

Tags: jboss, jboss7.x, wildfly, jboss6.x, wildfly-8

I have tried below snippet

```
String path = System.getProperty("java.class.path");
```

I get

```
../wildfly-8.2.0.Final/jboss-modules.jar

 String modulepath = System.getProperty("jboss.module.path");
// ../wildfly-8.2.0.Final/jboss-modules.jar
```

and not the ones which i have added in modules

when i try

```
StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
for (URL url :
    ((URLClassLoader) (Thread.currentThread()
    .getContextClassLoader())).getURLs()) {
    buffer.append(new File(url.getPath()));
    buffer.append(System.getProperty("path.separator"));
            }
```

Getting :

> java.lang.ClassCastException: org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader cannot be cast to java.net.URLClassLoader

Comment: What is your goal? JBoss Modules does not use a flat class path.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use getResourceAsStream on your application class path which is using the same class loader as your app.